# xsl getting original parent node and the other nodes where ParentID is that parent node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml as follows. Using xsl, I want to get nodes (parent node and all other node where parentItem points to that particular parent node)

```
<apis>
  <api>
     <name>myFirstApi</name>
     <itemNumber>1</itemNumber>
     <parentItem></parentItem>
     <parameter></parameter>
  </api>
   <api>
     <name>mySecondApi</name>
     <itemNumber>2</itemNumber>
     <parentItem>1</parentItem>
     <parameter>someparameter</parameter>
  </api>
  <api>
     <name>myThirdApi</name>
     <itemNumber>3</itemNumber>
     <parentItem></parentItem>
     <parameter></parameter>
  </api>
</apis>
```

For above example, I want to get first node, which has itemNumber 1, and second node, because second node has parentItem pointing to node 1.

As `<parameter>` node is not their in api 1, but it is there in itemNumber 2 where parentItem is 1, I want to add `<parameter>` value from itemNumber 2 to itemNumber 1.

Expected Output is:

```
  <apis>
  <api>
     <name>myFirstApi</name>
     <itemNumber>1</itemNumber>
     <parameter>someparameter</parameter>
  </api>
  <api>
     <name>myThirdApi</name>
     <itemNumber>3</itemNumber>
     <parentItem></parentItem>
     <parameter></parameter>
  </api>
</apis>
```

Comment: It's one thing getting the nodes, but another thing doing something with them! It might be better to say what you are trying to do, and showing the output you would like. For example, are you actually trying to nest the `api` elements based on the `parentItem` values? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Tim, I have changed my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn about the `xsl:key` here, as this makes looking up nodes in the element much straight-forward. In your case, you want to look up `api` elements by their `parentItem`, so you might define a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="parent" match="api" use="parentItem" />
```

Then, assuming you were positioned on a parent `api` element, you could get the "child" api, like so

```
<xsl:apply-template select="key('parent', itemNumber)" />
```

However, to solve your particular example, you probably want to start off with the XSLT identity template

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You would start off my selecting the `api` elements with a parent:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('parent', '')"/>
```

Then, you only need to write a template for changing any `parameter` node that is empty

```
<xsl:template match="parameter[. = '']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('parent', ../itemNumber)/parameter" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="parent" match="api" use="parentItem" />

    <xsl:template match="apis">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('parent', '')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="parameter[. = '']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('parent', ../itemNumber)/parameter" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`/apis/api[parentItem = '']` will more or less produce your expected output.

Comment: No, not really. An XPath expresssion selects result nodes, but it will never transform the input tree. Your path expression will select a set of `api` nodes, but the result will not be well-formed XML.